# division between values in dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, division

I have two dataframes (csv sheets) each with same number of rows (30,000 rows) and 50 columns in each. I would like to divide `df1` by `df2` in all cells column wise by taking row names as common.

Ex:

df1

```
rs sample1 sample1 sample2 sample3 .... sample50

tp1  3        5         7      17       25
tp10  10      25        47     37       45
tp25  110     125       147     370     145
```

df2

```
rs sample1 sample1 sample2 sample3 .... sample50

tp1  30        25         7      170      125
tp10  40      125        147     327      145
tp25  210     425       170     570     1457
```

I want to calculate each cell value between these dataframes by using rs as common in R. I tried the following:

```
df3 <- df1$sample1 / df2$sample2[ match( df1$rs , df2$rs ) ]
```

but it printed out values without row names.

My question is, how can I print the values across for all columns retaining the row names?

Comment: With the same number of rows and columns, when you say " divide... all cells column wise", what do you mean by "column wise". Why not just `df3 = df1 / df2`? If your row names are actually a column (which looks to be the case since they have a header) then `df3 = df1[, -1] / df2[, -1]`, then `df3$rs = df1$rs`.

Comment: for some reason, it does not look like a simple division as it keeps throwing the error messages. But if I do not assign to a dataframe and simply do a df1/df2, seems like it will output some result without output the common row names

Comment: It works  but without the reference to ist column. I would like to see the first column with those reference names for rows to be output as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide as suggested by Gregor: 
`df3=df1/df2`. The first column would become all NA since it is factor in your df. To correct it, just copy first column from your df1. `df3$rs<-df1$rs`